# How to add multiple line text in UIActionSheet

Tags: swift, xcode, uialertview, uiactionsheet, nsobject

[image]

How to add multi line text with custom font in UIActionSheet swift.I have tried \n.but this is not working.is this possible or not.

Here is the my code.

```
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "line 1.\n %C line 2,\n %C line", style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        print("User click Approve button")
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        print("User click Edit button")
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        print("User click Delete button")
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        print("User click Dismiss button")
    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        print("completion block")
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code.

```
let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Class", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
let course1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Computer Science(1st year) \n Digital Electronics", style: .default)
let course2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Computer Science(2nd year) \n Digital Electronics", style: .default)
let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
optionMenu.addAction(course1)
optionMenu.addAction(course2)
optionMenu.addAction(cancel)
self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

// Setting up the number of lines and doing a word wrapping        
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:[UIAlertController.self]).numberOfLines = 2
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:[UIAlertController.self]).lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

**Output**

[image: Output Image]

Comment: Thanks chirag for your valuable reply.this is work for multiple line can you please suggest me how to add multiple font..

Comment: Okay I will add.

Answer (score 3):

I'm showing the 2 text values in UIAlertAction.
To use multiple fonts, colors, and other attributes, we have to use `attributedText` property.
I used the following code.

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).numberOfLines = 0

let actionSheetController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Call", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
actionSheetController.view.tintColor = UIColor.red

for key in phoneNumbers.keys {
    let phoneNumber = phoneNumbers[key] ?? ""
    let actionTitle = "\(key)\n\(phoneNumber)"
    let phoneNumberAction = UIAlertAction(title: actionTitle, style: .default) { action -> Void in
        self.makeCall(phoneNumber)
    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(phoneNumberAction)

    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: actionTitle)

    let range = NSRange(location: key.count, length: attributedText.length - key.count)

    attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.gray, range: range)

    guard let label = (phoneNumberAction.value(forKey: "__representer")as? NSObject)?.value(forKey: "label") as? UILabel else { return }
    label.attributedText = attributedText
}

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: LOCALSTR("Cancel"), style: .cancel) { action -> Void in

}
actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)

present(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: Btw, I see another problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216417/ios-multiple-line-text-on-uialertaction

Comment: unable to access label property

Comment: @KedarSukerkar You mean ```guard let label = (phoneNumberAction.value(forKey: "__representer")as? NSObject)?.value(forKey: "label") as? UILabel else { return }``` does not work or ```label.attributedText = attributedText```?

Comment: Yes.....sorry that was mistake from my side.....i was accessing label before presenting alert. Thats why was getting nil... Also, i wasn't able to change the font property..any solutions for it.

Comment: @KedarSukerkar It's easy. You can just add the normal front.

Comment: yeah, i had added similar to this..attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: myFont, range: range)....but there was no effect